# What's a Linq query that will get each objX where objX.created = {newest}?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This one's turning out to be a brain teaser for me. I almost hate to ask for help for fear I might miss out on the endless, sleepless night trying to cypher this mystery. JK

I've got a C# project where I need to display a list of unique objects, but only the newest one based on the type of object. For discussion purposes, let's talk "fruit". Suppose I have a list of fruits, each with a "picked date". There is no primary key. So, my generic list of type "Fruit" might look like...

```
{'Apple','1/2/2010'}
{'Apple','11/12/2009'}
{'Apple','2/14/2010'}
{'Grape','5/2/2009'}
{'Orange','10/30/2009'}
{'Mango','2/13/2010'}
{'Apple','6/30/2009'}
{'Orange','10/5/2009'}
{'Grape','2/1/2010'}
```

I need to be able to cut down that list to only the newest of each type of fruit. The results should be...

```
{'Apple','2/14/2010'}
{'Orange','10/30/2009'}
{'Mango','2/13/2010'}
{'Grape','2/1/2010'}
```

In my real world situation, I'm using Linq to SQL. So, I'd like to stay in-bounds with what I've been doing.

This is probably something SO simple and, later on, I'm going to be embarassed I even asked. But, I need to know, so I guess I'll just have to make the sacrifice.

Comment: A multi-dimensional array is not an IEnumerable, you have to have a custom type or some other object type to run a LINQ query

Comment: It's a generic List<Fruit> where Fruit has two properties: Name, Picked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var query = from item in db.Items
            group item by item.Fruit into grouped
            select grouped.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
                          .First();
```

In other words, group by fruit name, and *for each group* order by date and take the first result.

Comment: I think I just wet myself a little... A Jon Skeet answer on a question by little ole me. :)

Comment: When Jon Skeet jumps in a pool, he doesn't get wet. The water gets Jon Skeet'd.

Comment: @casperOne: In what way does it only return the last date? Each group is a sequence of items - I'm ordering each group by date, and then returning the first element of the ordered sequence. That element will be the whole item, *not* just the date.

Comment: & @casperOne: It works great for me. I've already applied it in my app with no issue. I did mess up once and left off the .First() and it did what @casperOne said. So the .First() is absolutely needed in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform a grouping on the key (in this case, Fruit), and then order the group on the values (in this case, Created), selecting the first item from each group, ordered, like so:

```
from each f in FruitCreatedDates
group f by f.Created into g
select new 
{ 
    Fruit = g.Key, 
    Newest = g.OrderedByDescending(fr => fr.Created).First() 
};
```

Comment: Why bother with the anonymous type? Given the "Newest" value you can get at the fruit because it's part of the item...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with the Linq to SQL syntax, but in SQL you would use a distinct select, combined with a Order on the creation-date.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need a groupby and a max(date). I'm thinking purely in an SQL way, but I'm sure you'd be able to figure out the Linq for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Min` method, providing a selector lambda like this:

```
var list = new List<Fruit>() { 
    new Fruit() {Name = "Apple", Created = new DateTime(2010, 1, 2)},
    new Fruit() {Name = "Apple", Created = new DateTime(2010, 2, 2)},
    new Fruit() {Name = "Apple", Created = new DateTime(2010, 3, 2)},
    new Fruit() {Name = "Grape", Created = new DateTime(2011, 4, 2)},
    new Fruit() {Name = "Grape", Created = new DateTime(2011, 5, 2)},
    new Fruit() {Name = "Grape", Created = new DateTime(2011, 6, 2)},
};

var query =
        from fruit in list
        group fruit by fruit.Name into grouped
        select grouped.Min(f => f.Created);
```

Comment: That only returns the created date. I need the whole object to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you, I'd create a custom object to encapsulate this data.  This way you can run LINQ queries to your heart's content.

```
public struct Fruit
{
    public string Name;
    public string FreshDate;
}
```

Then I would run the query like this:

```
List<Fruit> fruitArray = new List<Fruit>
{
new Fruit { Name = "Apple", FreshDate = "1/2/2010"},
new Fruit { Name = "Apple", FreshDate = "11/12/2009"},
new Fruit { Name = "Apple", FreshDate = "2/14/2010"},
new Fruit { Name = "Grape", FreshDate = "5/2/2009"},
new Fruit { Name = "Orange", FreshDate = "10/30/2009"},
new Fruit { Name = "Mango", FreshDate = "2/13/2010"},
new Fruit { Name = "Apple", FreshDate = "6/30/2009"},
new Fruit { Name = "Orange", FreshDate = "10/5/2009"},
new Fruit { Name = "Grape", FreshDate = "2/1/2010"}
};

var resultArray = fruitArray.GroupBy(f => f.Name).Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => DateTime.Parse(f.FreshDate)).Last());
```

You shouldn't run the query on a multi-dimensional string array.  Easier to read on a custom object.

Comment: @masenkablast: Sorry, I meant to represent a generic list, not an array. That was just my poor way of representing the data to you.